# How to avoid data being exposed in DocuSign Clickwrap Call

Tags: javascript, c#, docusignapi

I'm seeking advice for a better solution for avoid data from being exposed in javascript.  The following is sample code provided by DocuSign for call Clickwrap API.  Is it possible to make this javascript call from C#?

```
<div id="ds-terms-of-service"></div>

<script src="https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js"></script>

<script>docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({
   environment: 'https://demo.docusign.net',
   accountId: 'c4b87cc4-0000-433f-8c6a-a52209d4942a',
   clickwrapId: 'ba495cf9-1111-4b9e-9a99-be0357d683ff',
   clientUserId: '1234'
   '#ds-terms-of-service'
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** you can use [this endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/accounts/clickwraps/createhasagreed/) to retrieve a URL that's unique to the specific user that is agreeing to the clickwrap. That URL won't have any information that you don't want to expose. (the URL you get has a special unique token that can only be used for this particular user and does not expose anything else).

One approach is to get this information on the server when user interact with your app so it's not exposed directly on the source.
To see how this is done, you can look at the new [MyClickwrap sample app](https://sampleapps.docusign.com/myclickwrap/). You can get the code downloaded (C#, .NET.Core) from [GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-myclickwrap-csharp) to see how it was built

Comment: I referred to code flow stated on https://myclickwrap.sampleapps.docusign.com/myclickwrap/.  Step 3 stated that using javascript API to render Clickwrap and the API takes 4 parameters including AccountID. Doesn't it expose sensitive info?

Comment: Sorry, I think we're not explaining this part very well. While if you hardcode this information it does exposes sensitive information, this app doesn't work this way. It uses a server API call to get the information and then the server send this back to the client so it's not visible to the user. 
Check the code on GitHub to see how it works - https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-myclickwrap-csharp

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply but still people can use browser developer tool to see the parameters being passed to JavaScript API, is that correct?.  We tested with the Terms & Condition sample and do see the account ID.

Comment: Let me update my answer, there's another endpoint to do that.

Comment: Maybe I'll write a blog post about this. Seems like something we didn't document much yet...

Comment: Thanks again Inbar.  Correct me if I'm wrong.  The endpoint you updated is for checking if user agreed, isn't it?  I tried your sample and I was able to get your account ID and clickwrap ID from browser developer tool and then paste them on my own page to show your Clickwrap popup.  This is my main concern.

Comment: this endpoint has dual purposes. It both checks and then if the answer is no - it returns a unique URL you can use to let user agree to the clickWrap, but that URL has a token and does not expose the accountId or clickwrapID

Comment: So far the examples we found seem like all using JavaScript to embed Clickwrap in an application. (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/how-to/embed-clickwraps/).  Is there any API that can be called from C# for embedding the Clickwrap in our application.

Comment: I'm working to test this C# code and will get back to you soon.

Comment: Checking in to see if any update on this.  Thanks.